# Calculating total value for a given financial period results in an 'list' object has no attribute 'sum' error

Tags: python, excel, list

My code

```
tperiod = list(df.groupby(['Period']),['Val.in rep.cur.'].sum())
```

Error Msg

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sum'

What I'm trying to do
Using Pandas Groupby to calculate the total value for a given financial period on a spreadsheet. Period and "Val.in rep.cur." are both headings for an excel column.

Does anyone know if I'd made a syntax error? Thanks for your help.

George Ng

Comment: There's several things wrong here, as far as I can tell. You are doing `df.groupby(['Period']),['Val.in rep.cur.'].sum()` did you mean `df.groupby(['Period, 'Val.in rep.cur.']).sum()`? Notice, in what you have, you are calling `.sum` in that list, `['Val.in rep.cur.'].sum()` which doesn't make any sense

Comment: Actually, there was a typo in the statement, it should be
```tperiod = list(df.groupby(['Period'])['Val.in rep.cur.'].sum())``` instead and now works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the sum of all the numbers in a list, you do `sum(list)`, not `list.sum()`.